# Update any input field among many

Tags: react-native

I'm new to React Native and I'm trying to update input fields on text input change in React Native the same way I do it in React but it's not working

**What I've tried**

Tried to search all over the internet and found that the only way that works is the one below.

```
const Register= () => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
    });

    const handleChange = (newTxt) =>{
        setUser({...user, name: newTxt})
    };
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        placeholder='Name...'
        value={user.name}
        onChangeText={handleChange}
      />
      <TextInput
        placeholder='Email...'
        name='email'
        value={user.email}
        onChangeText={handleChange}
      />
      <TextInput
        placeholder='Passowrd...'
        name='password'
        value={user.password}
        onChangeText={handleChange}
      />
      <Button title='Sign Up' onPress={signUp}/>
    </View>
  )
}
```

**Desired implementation**

Is there any way to update any field this way? For example, in case, I had many input fields?

```
const Register= () => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
    });

    
    const handleChange = (newTxt) =>{
        setUser(prevState => ({...prevState,  [e.target.value]: e.nativeEvent.text }))
    };
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        placeholder='Name...'
        value={user.name}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <TextInput
        placeholder='Email...'
        name='email'
        value={user.email}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <TextInput
        placeholder='Passowrd...'
        name='password'
        value={user.password}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <Button title='Sign Up' onPress={signUp}/>
    </View>
  )
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This won't work in React Native's text input sadly, but you can always create a custom component that supports that, my suggestion would be:

```
const NamedTextInput = (props)=>{
    const handleChange = (value)=>{
        props.onChangeText(value, props.name)
    }
    return(
        <TextInput
          {...props}
          onChangeText={handleChange }  
        />
    )
}
```

and you can use it like this

```
const handleChange = (value, name) => {
    setUser(prevState=>({...prevState, [name]:value}))
};

return (
...
...
<NamedTextInput
     placeholder='Email'
     name='email'
     value={user.email}
     onChangeText={handleChange}
/>
...
...
)
```

or of course you can use something like formik instead

Comment: Thanks, @RodSar, I thought I didn't Google well enough but I've totally accepted that it can't be done the React's way.

Comment: np, let me know if it works for your case